# .submit() Jquery method attached to dynamically loaded form is not submitting any "POST" data in browsers except IE

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

This is a bit weird but this time I have came across something that works on IE and not on other browsers like firefox and chrome..

Here is the issue:

I am dynamically loading a part of a page, that contains a form, into my existing page with jquery `.load()` method.

I have used .on method to attach event handler for the newly added elements.

But when I click on submit button the form submit method works fine, but it doesnt send any data in post query ( by the way, I have specified `form method=POST"`)

The main issue is that before I fire the `.load()` method to obtain new elements and replace the existing ones, the `.submit()` works FINE. IT SENDS THE POST DATA.

But after the dom is replaced, there is no data in POST.

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".s_edit",function() 
{$(this).parents('tr').children('form').submit();});
```

`.s_edit` is the form submit button:

PHP/HTML code (CodeIgniter):

```
<tr>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/userlist/inline_edit/<?php echo $r['id'];?>">
        <td><input class="record_edit" type="text" name="name" id="name<?php echo $r['id'] ?>"/></td>
        <td><input class="record_edit" type="text" name="age" id="age<?php echo $r['id']; ?>"/></td>
        <td>
            <span class="record_edit">
                <input id="gen_m<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" type="radio" name="gender" value="m"/>Male<br/>
                <input id="gen_f<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" type="radio" name="gender" value="f"/>Female
            </span>
        </td>
        <td><input class="record_edit datepick" type="text" name="joining_date" id="joining_date<?php echo $r['id']; ?>"/></td>
        <td>
            <div class="record_edit">
                <input type="submit" value="save" class="s_edit"/>
                <input type="button" class="cancel_edit" value="Cancel"/>    
            </div>
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `tr` can have `td` as direct children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have `<tr><form><td>`, other browsers are stripping the form element out, or re-arranging it in the DOM tree.

I.E. In Firefox,

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <form>
            <td>a</td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

goes to

```
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <form></form>
            <td>a</td>

    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Hence, your form is no longer wrapping the elements in the td.

Comment: so how to fix this? cause i somehow want to implement inline edit thus i need a form on each row..

Comment: and by the way,this markup and script works fine before invoking the jquery .load() method...after that.. blank post requests...except for IE.

Comment: I would say it worked originally because the browser may have interpreted it differently to how jQuery tried to use it... something to do with the internal DOM node structure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok..I replaced the table formatting with div and table display properties in css..firefox and mozilla as Benno suggested was getting rearranged except for IE..still it somehow worked before invoking .load method of jquery..but now its working completely fine..